# Performance hit with WAITFOR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using this code to replicate Data Driven Subscriptions in MSSQL 2008.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2008/08/13/data-driven-subscriptions-in-sql-server-2005-standard-edition.aspx

As part of the queueing system it uses a

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';
```

I'm planning on using this for over 200+ reports.

Will I have to schedule them to run at different times or will it all happily run queueing the reports and what is the performance hit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is essentially no perormance hit (to other queries using) waitfor - its what it is amongst other things designed ie - releasing the processor to do other things. The question is what else is scheduled for then - Backups etc? I would be inclined to test the time taken for each report and write to a table (for your 201+ th report). It really depends on how intensive your reports are - and the fact that you are scheduling them for a quiet time suggests your resources are not limitless. I would be inclined to schedule reports for different time - even if only 5 seconds apart - specially if preceeding the report takes between 1 and 4 seconds. The sql batch will then be slightly more complex but run more smoothly. Also a query which tells you when reports have overlapped can help your scheduling. If you have parallelismn turned off and have 4 processors, you may run 4 reports at a time, but check your disk queue as well.

Comment: This server is doing nothing else but running reports and these particular reports will be scheduled early hours. Most reports take about 2 seconds to run with a few reports taking very max 25 seconds.